# Excel Formula Static value increment

Tags: excel

I want to increment a static value in a formula as I drag across the column.

```
="1"
```

If I drag this to other rows it stays the same, even if I drag it from the corner with a `+` sign. How do I increment it with `1` as I drag across the same column.

Comment: Increment by 1 with respect to _what_ other cell/column?

Comment: Do you mean `=column(A:A)` dragged right?

Comment: I don't want it with respect to other columns. I just want to increase its own, like `i++` in c# for example

Comment: @user11138753, tried this doesn't work

Comment: If I put a reference to a Cell like this:`=""&A$2+1&""`, then in `A2` I enter `1`, will this work. can you please correct this formula `=""&A$2+1&""`

Comment: If A1 is 1, then B1=A1+1 and C1 = B1+$A$1 , then drag right...

Comment: @user726720: You are stating _"If I drag this to other columns it stays the same..."_. 
This means your idea is to drag the cell contents from Column A to Column B and so on.

But then again, you are stating _"...How do I increment it with 1 as I drag across the same column."_
This would mean the opposite. (i.e. to drag the cell contents from say Row 1 to Row 2 and so on).
You might've to consider rephrasing your question to get a better answer.

Comment: It was drag to other rows and not columns sorry for the typo. Anyways i have a solution using row function. =row(a1). This seems to work as i need it. I will post it properly as an answer soon, once im back at desk

Answer (score 1):

`="1"` is a string, not a number. Instead, enter a simple 1 in, say, A1 and 2 in B1 to show your intention. Then select A1:B1 and drag the little square at the bottom of the frame around the selection to the right. The cells will fill with sequential values.

Comment: I need to do it thru a formula

Comment: @user726720: Write `=COLUMN(A1)` in cell A1 and then drag the '+' fill handle across the columns until the desired column.

Comment: @KarthickGanesan: This doesn't work

Comment: @KarthickGanesan I tested it on Excel 2013

Comment: @Variatus Doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the 'Fill Series' option.

**Excel 2007 and later**

1. Once you drag across columns using the + fill handle as you stated, you should see an 'Auto Fill Options' context drop-down icon like the one shown in the image below.

   [image: autofilloptioncontextdropdownicon]
2. Click on the icon you should see a list of options, click 'Fill Series' radio button and you should be done.

   [image: autofillcontextdropfillseriesradiobutton]
3. The series should've come up as expected.

   [image: fillseriesresult]

Cheers !